# TigerVNC Server Installed - Black screen

Tags: screen, display-resolution, vnc, tightvncserver

So I just followed this source for instructions on how to setup a VNC Server (TigerVNC):
https://tecadmin.net/install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/

About halfway through, right before **Step 3** I was able to VNC/remote into my Ubuntu box but it was displaying a desktop that wasn't currently in front of me (on my Ubuntu box). On my Ubuntu box, while my Windows box was VNC/remoted in, I was trying to find the desktop that it was communicating with, if that makes sense, but nada.

So I continued, skipping Step 3, because I had already installed a VNC viewer prior to the VNC Server. Followed the instructions thinking, "okay, I guess once I'm done with these instructions it will remote back in and I'll be able to control the actual desktop that my Ubuntu box is displaying."

I was wrong.

I finished the instructions without error and now when I remote in, it's a black screen.

Just in case, I rebooted my Ubuntu box but still connecting and displaying a black screen.

My only thought is maybe the geometry portion is incorrect? I've only tried using these two resolutions:

Default (per instructions): 1024x768
Modified to: 1280x1024

Any insight on this? I'm trying to run my Ubuntu box in a headless fashion, need to be able to VNC into it from different PCs at home whenever I need to do work on it.

Edit: I forgot to mention, my Windows box has UltraVNC as well as TigerVNC, both application display a black screen after authenticating the connection to my Ubuntu box.